# PySpark Error while trying to analyze twitter dataset

Tags: exception, pyspark, types, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to analyze massive Twitter dumps which my Professor collected over the period of 2 years into multiple parquet files. I have run all my code with one file and all the codes run smoothly but I'm consistently facing issues when I'm trying to read and analyze all the parquet files. This is one example of the error I'm facing. I'm trying to create a temp table view so that I can run SQL queries to query data.
Please find my Spark Configuration:

```
[('spark.app.name', 'Colab'),
 ('spark.driver.memory', '50g'),
 ('spark.app.id', 'local-1636990273526'),
 ('spark.memory.offHeap.size', '20g'),
 ('spark.app.startTime', '1636990272425'),
 ('spark.driver.port', '40705'),
 ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
 ('spark.driver.host', '3c3ebb00872b'),
 ('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', 'file:/content/spark-warehouse'),
 ('spark.memory.offHeap.enabled', 'true'),
 ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
 ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
 ('spark.master', 'local[*]'),
 ('spark.submit.pyFiles', ''),
 ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
 ('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true'),
 ('spark.executor.memory', '50g')]
```

The spark dataframe has 393 million rows and 383 columns.

Whenever I try to run the following code:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("twitlogs")

tbl = spark.sql("""
  SELECT * FROM twitlogs LIMIT 20
  """)

tbl.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o114.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 34 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 34.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 1219) (3c3ebb00872b executor driver): org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file file:///content/drive/MyDrive/ProjAbe/tweets-2020-08-25T09___30___02Z.parq. Column: [geo], Expected: double, Found: BINARY
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.unsupportedSchemaColumnConvertError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:570)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$SliceIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:268)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetVectorUpdaterFactory.constructConvertNotSupportedException(ParquetVectorUpdaterFactory.java:1077)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetVectorUpdaterFactory.getUpdater(ParquetVectorUpdaterFactory.java:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:168)
    ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2352)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2591)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2533)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file file:///content/drive/MyDrive/ProjAbe/tweets-2020-08-25T09___30___02Z.parq. Column: [geo], Expected: double, Found: BINARY
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.unsupportedSchemaColumnConvertError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:570)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$SliceIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:268)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetVectorUpdaterFactory.constructConvertNotSupportedException(ParquetVectorUpdaterFactory.java:1077)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetVectorUpdaterFactory.getUpdater(ParquetVectorUpdaterFactory.java:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:168)
    ... 16 more
```

I have run the same code with just 1 parquet file which has about 183000 rows and it runs smoothly.
I also get the same error when I run this code trying to find missing values:

```
def get_dtype(df,colname):
    return [dtype for name, dtype in df.dtypes if name == colname][0]

df_mis = df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull() if get_dtype(df, c) not in ['double', 'float'] else isnan(col(c)), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])

df_mis.show()
```

I think its a memory issue but not sure how to deal with it. I have tried to spend a whole day doing extensive research about the whole issue and have come up with nothing. Please help.

Update 11/16/21: After being asked to include the schema, I could only include a part of it as there's a word limit in stackoverflow. Please note that the dataset has 383 columns.

```
root
 |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- display_text_range: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- truncated: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_status_id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_status_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_user_id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_user_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geo: double (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: double (nullable = true)
 |-- place: double (nullable = true)
 |-- contributors: string (nullable = true)
 |-- is_quote_status: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- quote_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- reply_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- retweet_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- favorite_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- favorited: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- filter_level: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp_ms: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_translator_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_protected: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- user_verified: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- user_followers_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user_friends_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user_listed_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user_favourites_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user_statuses_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user_created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_utc_offset: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_time_zone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_geo_enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- user_lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_contributors_enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- user_is_translator: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_background_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_background_image_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_background_image_url_https: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_background_tile: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_link_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_sidebar_border_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_sidebar_fill_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_text_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_use_background_image: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_image_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_image_url_https: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_profile_banner_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_default_profile: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- user_default_profile_image: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- user_following: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_follow_request_sent: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_notifications: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entities_hashtags: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entities_urls: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entities_user_mentions: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entities_symbols: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_display_text_range: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_truncated: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_in_reply_to_status_id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_in_reply_to_status_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_in_reply_to_user_id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_in_reply_to_user_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_in_reply_to_screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_translator_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_protected: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_verified: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_followers_count: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_friends_count: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_listed_count: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_favourites_count: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_statuses_count: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_utc_offset: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_time_zone: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_geo_enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_lang: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_contributors_enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_is_translator: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_background_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_background_image_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_background_image_url_https: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_background_tile: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_link_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_sidebar_border_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_sidebar_fill_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_text_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_use_background_image: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_image_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_image_url_https: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_profile_banner_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_default_profile: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_default_profile_image: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_following: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_follow_request_sent: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_user_notifications: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_geo: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_coordinates: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_place: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_contributors: double (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_is_quote_status: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status_extended_tweet_full_text: string (nullable = true)
```

Update 11/18/2021: I have made further discoveries about my error. It seems like some of the parquet files have schema for the column "geo" as string instead of double. After trying mergeSchema, it gives similar error. "Failed to merge fields 'geo' and 'geo'. Failed to merge incompatible data types double and string".

Comment: From the error does not seem to be a scaling issue, do report back if running the script on only the file with error `file:///content/drive/MyDrive/ProjAbe/tweets-2020-08-25T09___30___02Z.parq` succeeds.

Comment: I just ran it and it worked on this particular "parquet" file. What do I do now?

Comment: Can you include the schema of the dataframe to your question using `df.printSchema()`

Comment: I just updated my question with a part of `df.printSchema()` and couldn't include all of it because char limit constraint by stackoverflow.

Comment: I have made further discoveries about my error. It seems like some of the parquet files have schema for the column "geo" as string instead of double. After trying mergeSchema, it gives similar error. "Failed to merge fields 'geo' and 'geo'. Failed to merge incompatible data types double and string".